# Shell script - psql run multiple statements from a variable one by one in one transaction

Tags: postgresql, linux, scripting, psql

Im preparing a shell script to generate analyze command and all the commands will go to a variable.

```
echo $analyze_query

analyze tbl1;
analyze tbl2;
analyze tbl3;
```

Now I want to run one by one, and Im able to achieve that by using the below command.

```
for $i in $analyze_query
do
psql -h host -U user -d db -c"$i"
done
```

But this query will close and open a new connection for every command, Is there any way that I can run the one by one but in one session?

Comment: You can use `bash` co-processes, but that is rather complicated ([here](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/safe-backup) is an example). I see no benefit in running those commands in a single transaction; why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we can do it.

1. echo the variable and then pipe it to psql.

`echo "$analyze_query"  |  psql -h host -U user -d db`

2. Use () to group the command output then pipe it to psql.

`(for i in $analyze_query 
do
 echo $i
done ) |  psql -h host -U user -d db`